Convert Oracle Primavera Calendar data (clndr_data) from Database Table into readable format using SQL Query
I need to convert Calendar data in Primavera P6 database into a readable format using SQL Query in SQL Server. and the data look like this
(0||CalendarData()(
  (0||DaysOfWeek()(
    (0||1()())
    (0||2()(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))
    (0||3()(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))
    (0||4()(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))
    (0||5()(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))
    (0||6()(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))
    (0||7()(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))))
  (0||VIEW(ShowTotal|N)())
  (0||Exceptions()(
    (0||0(d|41640)())
    (0||1(d|41670)())
    (0||2(d|41671)())
    (0||3(d|41760)())
    (0||4(d|41797)())
    (0||5(d|41848)())
    (0||6(d|41849)())
    (0||7(d|41883)())
    (0||8(d|41898)())
    (0||9(d|41934)())
    (0||10(d|41984)())
    (0||11(d|41998)())
    (0||12(d|42005)())
    (0||13(d|42054)())
    (0||14(d|42055)())
    (0||15(d|42125)())
    (0||16(d|42161)())
    (0||17(d|42202)())
    (0||18(d|42203)())
    (0||19(d|42247)())
    (0||20(d|42263)())
    (0||21(d|42319)())
    (0||22(d|42349)())
    (0||23(d|42363)())
    (0||24(d|42370)())
    (0||25(d|42408)())
    (0||26(d|42409)())
    (0||27(d|42492)())
    (0||28(d|42525)())
    (0||29(d|42558)())
    (0||30(d|42559)())
    (0||31(d|42613)())
    (0||32(d|42629)())
    (0||33(d|42674)())
    (0||34(d|42716)())
    (0||35(d|42730)())
    (0||36(d|42737)())
    (0||37(d|42763)())
    (0||38(d|42765)())
    (0||39(d|42856)())
    (0||40(d|42889)())
    (0||41(d|42912)())
    (0||42(d|42913)())
    (0||43(d|42978)())
    (0||44(d|42994)())
    (0||45(d|43027)())
    (0||46(d|43080)())
    (0||47(d|43094)())
    (0||48(d|43101)())
    (0||49(d|43147)())
    (0||50(d|43148)())
    (0||51(d|43221)())
    (0||52(d|43253)())
    (0||53(d|43266)())
    (0||54(d|43343)())
    (0||55(d|43360)())
    (0||56(d|43411)())
    (0||57(d|43445)())
    (0||58(d|43459)())
    (0||59(d|43466)())
    (0||60(d|43501)())
    (0||61(d|43502)())
    (0||62(d|43586)())
    (0||63(d|43617)())
    (0||64(d|43621)())
    (0||65(d|43622)())
    (0||66(d|43708)())
    (0||67(d|43724)())
    (0||68(d|43766)())
    (0||69(d|43810)())
    (0||70(d|43824)())
    (0||71(d|43831)())
    (0||72(d|43855)())
    (0||73(d|43857)())
    (0||74(d|43952)())
    (0||75(d|43976)())
    (0||76(d|43988)())
    (0||77(d|44013)(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))
    (0||78(d|44074)())
    (0||79(d|44090)())
    (0||80(d|44149)())
    (0||81(d|44157)(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|16:00)())))
    (0||82(d|44176)())
    (0||83(d|44190)())
    (0||84(d|44224)())
    (0||85(d|44239)())
    (0||86(d|44240)())
    (0||87(d|44278)())
    (0||88(d|44299)())
    (0||89(d|44317)())
    (0||90(d|44329)())
    (0||91(d|44330)())
    (0||92(d|44342)())
    (0||93(d|44354)())
    (0||94(d|44397)())
    (0||95(d|44418)())
    (0||96(d|44439)())
    (0||97(d|44443)(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))
    (0||98(d|44452)())
    (0||99(d|44455)())
    (0||100(d|44457)(
      (0||0(s|08:00|f|12:00)())
      (0||1(s|13:00|f|17:00)())))
    (0||101(d|44488)())
    (0||102(d|44504)())
    (0||103(d|44555)())
    (0||104(d|44579)())
    (0||105(d|44593)())
    (0||106(d|44594)())
    (0||107(d|44643)())
    (0||108(d|44683)())
    (0||109(d|44684)())
    (0||110(d|44716)())
    (0||111(d|44718)())
    (0||112(d|44751)())
    (0||113(d|44772)())
    (0||114(d|44804)())
    (0||115(d|44820)())
    (0||116(d|44842)())
    (0||117(d|44858)())
    (0||118(d|44949)())
    (0||119(d|44961)())
    (0||120(d|45008)())
    (0||121(d|45038)())
    (0||122(d|45047)())
    (0||123(d|45050)())
    (0||124(d|45082)())
    (0||125(d|45105)())
    (0||126(d|45126)())
    (0||127(d|45169)())
    (0||128(d|45185)())
    (0||129(d|45196)())
    (0||130(d|45285)())
    (0||131(d|45316)())
    (0||132(d|45332)())
    (0||133(d|45363)())
    (0||134(d|45392)())
    (0||135(d|45393)())
    (0||136(d|45413)())
    (0||137(d|45434)())
    (0||138(d|45460)())
    (0||139(d|45535)())
    (0||140(d|45551)())
    (0||141(d|45596)())
    (0||142(d|45651)())
    (0||143(d|45686)())
    (0||144(d|45687)())
    (0||145(d|45717)())
    (0||146(d|45747)())
    (0||147(d|45748)())
    (0||148(d|45778)())
    (0||149(d|45815)())
    (0||150(d|45835)())
    (0||151(d|45870)())
    (0||152(d|45905)())
    (0||153(d|45916)())
    (0||154(d|45974)())
    (0||155(d|46016)())
    (0||156(d|46070)())
    (0||157(d|46071)())
    (0||158(d|46102)())
    (0||159(d|46104)())
    (0||160(d|46143)())
    (0||161(d|46169)())
    (0||162(d|46179)())
    (0||163(d|46225)())
    (0||164(d|46260)())
    (0||165(d|46265)())
    (0||166(d|46281)())
    (0||167(d|46381)())))))

The data contains information regarding

What days are working and non-working in a week along with hours.
Exception Dates(Mostly public holidays and non working days and working days which are marked as non working days in week data)

What I need is to convert this data into Two Tables
Table 1: DaysOfWeek

Table 2: Exceptions_dates

What I have Tried
I tried to convert the data into XML format using string function like
WITH CalendarCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        clndr_id,
        CAST(clndr_data AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS clndr_data_str
    FROM [dbo].[CALENDAR] WHERE clndr_id = 641
    AND clndr_data IS NOT NULL
),
TransformedCalendarCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        clndr_id,
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            REPLACE(
                                                REPLACE(
                                                    REPLACE(
                                                        REPLACE(
                                                            clndr_data_str, 
                                                            '(0||', '<'
                                                        ), 
                                                        '()(', '><'
                                                    ), 
                                                    ')()', '/>'
                                                ), 
                                                '()', ''
                                            ), 
                                            '|', ''
                                        ), 
                                        '<)', '<'
                                    ),
                                    '<(', '<'
                                ),
                                '< ', '<'
                            ),
                            '>', '><'
                        ),
                        '><<', '><'
                    ),
                    '< >', ''
                ),
                '><', '><'
            ),
            '<', '<'
        ) AS cleaned_clndr_data
    FROM CalendarCTE
)
SELECT *
FROM TransformedCalendarCTE

But was not successful. Also tried
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(s|08:00|f|12:00)', clndr_data) > 0 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data) > 0 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|08:00|f|12:00)', clndr_data) + 1) > 0 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|08:00|f|12:00)', clndr_data) + 1) + 1) > 0 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|08:00|f|12:00)', clndr_data) + 1) + 1) + 1) > 0 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|08:00|f|12:00)', clndr_data) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) > 0 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|13:00|f|17:00)', clndr_data, CHARINDEX('(s|08:00|f|12:00)', clndr_data) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) > 0 THEN 'Saturday'
    END AS NonWorkingDay
FROM 
    [dbo].[CALENDAR] WHERE clndr_id = 641;

I am getting Sunday as the non working day in a week which is correct, but if data is changed the query is returning null. So that was also unsuccessful.

So what have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a free contract coding service, we're volunteers here to help you fix code you've already tried to write and use unsuccessfully.

@AlwaysLearning, Thank you I understand the purpose of Stackoverflow and I have Updated the question.

How's the data stored in your table? as one long string with newlines or what? I don't quite understand the format they use, is there some spec? I still think your question is a bit too broad to solve, but maybe someone already done this once

What actual database are you working in? You mention Oracle, Primacera and SQL Server? Presumably you only need the syntax for one of them?

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

@siggemannen The data is in text format. I also have difficulty in understanding the format they use.
Primavera Reader Library MPXJ process this data can be viewed here https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/blob/a95b6f487c95794389bfa0b2a2011c72043c11a4/src/main/java/net/sf/mpxj/primavera/PrimaveraReader.java#L471C7-L489C8. They use StructuredTextParser. But I am trying to parse it using SQL Script.

@DaleK SQL Server
